# Contact form handler suddenly doesn’t send emails to Gmail

Tags: php, forms, email

I did a “raw” PHP contact form sender a year ago, tested many times, it worked.
It should just send an email to a Gmail account with the submitted email address or contact form parameters included in email body.

Now on redesign I got back to the contact form, tested it randomly and it doesn’t send anything at all. No error messages, the submitted form never arrives in the main Gmail inbox, unlike it used to.

```
<?php
$errors = '';
$myemail = 'x@gmail.com';
$noreply = 'x@y.com';

if (empty($_POST['email']))
{
    $errors .= "\n Error: Please provide an e-mail address where we can send the newsletter and special deals";
}

$email_address = $_POST['email'];

if (!preg_match(
    "/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/i",
    $email_address))
{
    $errors .= "\n Error: Invalid email address";
}

if (empty($errors))
{
    $to = $myemail;
    $email_subject = "Contact form submission: $email_address";
    $email_body = "You have received a newsletter signup. ".
        "Email: $email_address";

    $headers = "From: $noreply\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address";

    mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
    //redirect to the 'thank you' page
    header('Location: newsletter_submit.html');
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Contact form handler</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <!-- This page is displayed only if there is some error -->
    <?php
    echo nl2br($errors);
    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

It did happen with another similar form on this website, I wonder if something’s wrong with the code (althought it worked once) or Gmail changed something. I tried whitelisting the form sender email, but nothing changed.

Comment: Your system may not be setup to show errors. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything. Plus, your server may have been blacklisted.

Comment: Also, replace `mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);` with  `if(mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers)){ echo "mail sent"; } else { echo "error, check your logs"; }` - If you see "mail sent", PHP/server has done its job. What happens after that, is beyond your control.

Comment: Maybe you should check if your server haven't been **blacklisted** for sending spam, it could be probable if you are using a **shared hosting**

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that our mail server rejected same-domain emails. I changed the "myemail" to a gmail account, and the "noreply" to the actual "email server" mail address, then the forms suddenly appeared again in the gmail inbox. -.-

Anyway, thanks for the ideas, it helped me narrowing down the possible bugs list.